# How to make middle div acting like a fixed positioned header when middle div go to the top place by mouse scrolling

Tags: jquery, css

I've some section. Let's they are:

1. **Header** (Medium height's content)
2. **Remaining Section** (Small height's content)
3. **Content** (Extra Large height's content)

Let's all the section is visible at start. As **Content** section is Extra large, we can see some portion of that section at first. The normal behavior of browsers are:

If we scroll down the mouse a little bit, some portion of  **Header** section will be disappearing and some more portion of **Content** section will be visible. If we scroll down the mouse more, **Header** will be disappeared completely and some more portion of **Content** will be visible. Now, **Remaining Section** is on top place as Header disappeared for scrolling down mouse. So, the visible part of webpage is:

1. **Remaining Section**
2. **Content**

If we scroll down the mouse more, **Remaining Section** will be disappeared too and only visible part is now **Content** section.

Those are the normal behavior of browsers. Now, I'm trying to do this:

When, **Header** section will be disappeared by scrolling down mouse, **Remaining Section** will take place of header and set to the top position (Still it's in normal behavior). At that time, **Remaining Section** will be `position: fixed` at that **top position** and act like a fixed header. So, how much we scroll down the mouse and go through all the portion of Content, that **Remaining Section** will be visible all the time at that top position. I think, only with CSS, it won't be possible. Because, if I apply:

```
.remaining {
   position: fixed;
   top: 600px;
}
```

It'll be in middle position all the time. But, I want that will be fixed at top position when **Header** section disappeared at the time of mouse scrolling. Again, when scroll up the mouse a lot everything should act like normal like **Header** visible and **Remaining Section** go to the below **Header** etc. So, that kind of CSS don't help me.

So, how can I set Remaining Section fixed when disappearing the header and reset everything when appearing header by scrolling mouse?

[Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/xjh71304/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An elegant solution by [Guil Hernandez](https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/forum-tip-create-a-sticky-navigation-with-css-and-jquery-2) would fit your needs perfectly.

Add a single class to your CSS:

```
.remaining-scrolled {
    top:0;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
}
```

And add just a few lines of jQuery:

```
var  mn = $(".remaining");
mns = "remaining-scrolled";
hdr = $("#header").height();

$(window).scroll(function() {
   if( $(this).scrollTop() > hdr ) {
      mn.addClass(mns);
   } else {
      mn.removeClass(mns);
   }
});
```

And your effect is achieved. Here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ax3uyk7k/).